# Can't compile dbus-cxx tools

Tags: c++, dbus

Help! I may have made a huge mistake in committing my project to use dbus-cxx. That library appears to have been abandoned by its author, and the mailing list is closed to new members.
Here's my problem:

1. There is NO documentation on using dbux-cxx to send or receive dbus messages consisting of non-POD data. Clearly the expectation is that you'll use the dbus-cxx tools to generate C++ code from dbus introspection XML.
2. The tools won't compile.
3. The only support is via the mailing list, which has been abandoned.

Here’s the compiler error message:

```
arg.cpp: In member function ‘std::string Arg::stubsignature()’: 
arg.cpp:84:34: error: no matching function for call to ‘signature(DBus::Type)’
  return DBus::signature( type() );
                                 ^
```

Here are the offending lines:

```
82: std::string Arg::stubsignature()
83: {
84:   return DBus::signature( type() );
85: }
86: 
87: DBus::Type Arg::type()
88: {
89:   if ( not signature.is_singleton() ) return DBus::TYPE_INVALID;
90:   //if ( not signature.begin().is_basic() ) return DBus::TYPE_INVALID;
91:   return signature.begin().type();
92: }
```

From what I can see, the compiler is correct - there is no function with that signature.

At this point, my only option is to hack everything into a std::vector and extract it on the other side.

Any clues, hints, links to support sites, etc. would be appreciated.
Thanks,

-Nick

Answer (score 0):

Rolling back from revision 213 to revision 207 from the SVN repository removed the offending code.